# Can't disable the debugging logs in latest version of Flurry 2.8.4 in iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, flurry

I'm using latest version of Flurry SDK for iPhone. It works better than the earlier version. But I can't disable the debugging logs in console, as per their instruction

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {    

   [FlurryAPI setDebugLogEnabled:NO];

   [FlurryAPI startSession:#FLURRY_ID]; 

}
```

But still its logging in my console

> Flurry: Initialized session from
>   scratch with startTime[2011-03-12
>   05:54:58 +0000]
>
> Flurry: Created active session with
>   API
>
> Flurry: Session reports on close
>   enabled[1]
>
> Flurry: Session reports on pause
>   enabled[1]
>
> Flurry: Event logging enabled[1]
>
> Flurry: Finish starting session with
>   apiKey
>
> Flurry: Sending sessions to server
>   withTimeout[0]
>
> Flurry: Creating HTTP data from
>   sessions
>
> Flurry: cacheTimeStamp[0]
>   numCachedItems[0]
>
> Flurry: protocol[15] platform[2]
>   agent[47]

Answer (score 5):

Please email us at iphonesupport@flurry.com so we can further diagnose your issue. Support usually involves discussing account details, however, once we determine the underlying cause we can post the answer here so the community has the insight of our findings.

Thanks for your feedback.

**UPDATE**

We were able to verify the issue.  An incorrect configuration flag was set on the initial release of 2.8.4 that caused this behavior. Any downloads of the 2.8.4 SDK after 3/13 will not experience this behavior.  Please download the current build of 2.8.4 if you received the SDK prior to this date.

Again, thank you for the feedback.

Answer (score 0):

One of the projects I was working on had this same issue. (I did download the SDK in the timeframe suggested by Anthony W).

I simply fixed this by replacing the libFlurry.a file in my project.